# Java JSON Jar NoClassDefFound Caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, eclipse, error-handling, libraries

I have a simple java file packaged as a Jar on a server called by a PHP script. I have the "json-simple-1.1.1" library included in my java program. However, when I run it gives me the below error. I've added the json-simple jar to my project and import the correct classes. From what I've read it doesn't seem to be adding the json-simple library to my manifest file. Any ideas on how to fix this. I'm using eclipse if that helps.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: Might be you'll need to add the libs to the manifest yourself, like presented [here](http://fraaargh.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/how-to-java-jars-and-manifestmf/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your library is probably not been loaded by classloader, so, if it is not in WEB-INF/lib, right click it and `Add to build Path`.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a web-inf/lib folder. All I have is a "Referenced Libraries" folder where the json-simple.jar library. When I right click - build path - it already says its added to the build path.

Comment: Hmm ok, so its probably the manifest, have a look at this link http://fraaargh.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/how-to-java-jars-and-manifestmf/ @Hanno provided

Comment: what do I put in place of "myCustomLibPath2"? My Current manifest looks like this

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: test.HelloWorld
Class-Path: myCustomLibPath2/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: It is the path where your jar is, from the root of the project.
Maybe this one can help you too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: This seems awfully complicated. Eclipse can't just create a jar file with the java file and the included libraries without having to manually add each 3rd party library to the manifest?